# How to show a list with links on header or footer in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, footer

I want to show a footer that contains a list with links, but when i add the links, the "li" becomes a button. How can i fix it?

Some code:

```
    <div data-role="footer">                    
        <ul data-role="listview">
             <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com"><span>Google</span></a>
             </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `ul` to `data-role="none"` , like this:

```
   <div data-role="footer">                    
        <ul data-role="none">
             <li>
                  <a href="www.google.com"><span>Google</span></a>
             </li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

**UPDATE**:
You could try the following to get your desired style for the `li` while making it work like a link:

```
<ul data-role="listview"> 
   <li style="cursor:pointer" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'">Google</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks for the answer, but this don't resolve my problem. When i do that, it shows the first element of that list: http://i.imgur.com/SXRT4.png but i want show it like the second element of the list

Comment: In your posted code, you only have one li element, why is the image you posted have two google items?

Comment: yes, i have added a second "ul" without link to see the difference. I want to show the first li (that contains a link) like the second (that don't contains any link) Thanks for your help!

Comment: '<div data-role="footer">                    
             <ul data-role="none">
                 <li>
                     <a href="www.google.com"><span>Google</span></a>
                   </li>                    
             </ul>
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>Google</li>
                </ul>
          </div>'

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new approach based on your last input, try it.

Comment: That's exactly all i want! Thanks for your help!